# Transfer Data from Oracle database 11G to MongoDB

Tags: sql, mongodb, oracle, oracle11gr2

I want to have an automatic timed transfer from Oracle database to MongoDB. In a typical RDBMBS scenario, i would have established connection between two databases by creating a dblink and transferred the data by using PL/SQL procedures. 
But i don't know what to do in MongoDB case; thus, how and what should i be implementing so that i can have an automatic transfer from Oracle database to MongoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at using Oracle Goldengate.  It has a MONGODB Handler.
https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/bd123110/gg-bd/GADBD/using-mongodb-handler.htm#GADBD-GUID-084CCCD6-8D13-43C0-A6C4-4D2AC8B8FA86

https://oracledb101.wordpress.com/2016/07/29/using-goldengate-to-replicate-to-mongodb/

Answer (score 0):

What type of data do you want to transfer from the Oracle database to MongoDB? If you just want to export/import a small number of tables on a set schedule, you could use something like [UTL_FILE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_file.htm#BABGGEDF) on the Oracle side to create a .csv export of the table(s) and use [DBMS_SCHEDULER](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm#CIHHBGGI) to schedule the export to happen automatically based on your desired time frame.

You could also use an application like `SQL Developer` to export tables as .csv files by browsing to the table the schema list, then Right Click -> Export and choosing the .csv format. You may also find it a little easier to use `UTL_FILE` and `DBMS_SCHEDULER` through SQL Developer instead of relying on `SQL*Plus`.

Once you have your .csv file(s), you can use [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) to import the data, though I'm not sure if `MongoDB` supports scheduled jobs like `Oracle` (I work primarily with the latter.) If you are using `Linux`, you could use `cron` to schedule a script that will import the .csv file on a scheduled interval.